# Data type normalization vs. query performance

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework-5

I'm working on a rather large application project and I am setting up my database to allow for well performing queries. I have a normalized database structure which I know can lead to speed issues as my dataset grows. My database is mapped to my ASP MVC project using Entity Framework. Let me give an example of the predicament I am facing:

I have a table, let's call it `Buildings`. `Buildings` can be of a number of different types, eg., houses, condos, hotels, motels etc. Each building then has about 20 possible many-to-one sub properties (eg., comments, reviews, phone numbers etc.). Now the number of each type of building can vary significantly, for example lets say I expect only 100 condos but 100,000 houses. If I lay out my structure like this:

Option 1:

```
buildings---->(condos, houses, etc)----->many-to-one properties.
```

where the middle tier of tables which hold the building types just contain a foreign key reference to buildings (or equivalently, include the building type as a column of buildings), then it means that if I want to do a search on the house type that I have to search through a lot of records in the buildings table needlessly.

PROS: less complex application logic and database.

CONS: makes simpler queries slower, corruption of buildings table could affect entire application.

Option 2:

```
(condos, houses, etc)----->many-to-one properties.
```

skip the buildings table altogether and create a separate table for each building type. The data structure would be the same for each, but the data stored within would be unique to each table (so still normalized). The problem here is that I would then need to create tables for each of the 20+ many-to-one properties for each building type.

PROS: queries on smaller types are fast regardless of other type sizes, no single point of failure for all types, can apply custom rules to each type if necessary, can apply different indexes if necessary (eg., nonclustered indexes on types which may be frequently deleted, such as buildings available for rent).

CONS: more complex application logic (possibly can be reduced through stored procedure interface) and db structure

Given these trade offs, which would you suggest to be a more valuable data structure in an application which should be able to support around 40,000 concurrent users? Is there another way altogether to do this?

Comment: Have you considering any nosql db like MongoDb?

Comment: I have but it would reduce the benefits from using entity framework with ASP.NET MVC, not to mention the data is naturally relational so an RDBMS is desirable.

Comment: The 40,000 concurrent users is a big challenge in that case. The nosql can use commodity, but RDBMS will require state of the art servers at backend.

Comment: True but I'm using a server cluster set to always on high-availability, so for the time being lets assume the concurrency isn't the issue

Comment: So, denormalize everything.

Comment: How live is the data? Are most uses reading/analyzing, or editing? How often is data updated?

Comment: @alex If I denormalize everything then I run the risk of my many-to-one properties making my tables too large (row-wise), which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan 

Some of the types are fairly static and will likely only be read and rarely updated or deleted (clustered index preferred).

Other types are more dynamic and have fairly short relevance lifespans (a few hours or days) so I plan to dump these to a cold storage db after they expire then delete them from the main db (nonclustered index preferred). 

All the types have a many-to-one comment property which may be frequently updated. It is this variance in the way the data will be used that has me leaning towards option 2.

Comment: @AleksandrAlbert Do users need access to all rows or only rows specific to them? (ex all buildings, or only buildings they own?)

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan The users would need access to all rows in this case, though results would usually be presented based on some filter (eg., by city, price, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should keep a highly normalized operational database for inserts, updates, and deletes, to minimize duplication and anomalies, and increase integrity and insert/update/delete performance.

You could then have a denormalized data warehouse-style database for selects, searching, analysis, spread across multiple servers.

You could simplify the ETL to the warehouse by using materialized views to create your denormalized queries, and have the materialized views refreshed on a schedule, such as every evening.

Comment: Well options 1 and 2 are both normalized, though option 2 is 'more' normalized I suppose. So would you suggest option 2?